# Detect window close command from child (iframe)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my html page from another website.

User does something in that iframe, and then the page closes itself. (that page isn't for me, I can't change the functionality of that)

I want my html page to detect this close command from child and then, change visiblity of the iframe to false.

How to do that??

Comment: *another website* You can't unless you setup cross-origin communication which requires the another website to implement it as well.

Comment: It is google plus sharing page!

Comment: well you can not change the parent in any way when it is in a different domain.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. The parent is mine, but child page is from Google. the child page wants to close page, but I want to detect and manage it, and just hide the iframe.

Comment: You could set up a timed loop to check the location of the child window.  If the location changes when the child page "closes", then you will be able to see that.

Comment: @EdManet Can you give me an example, and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current location and use use setInterval to start the loop.

```
var startingLocation = document.getElementById('myIFrame').location;
setInterval("checkChildLocation",1000);
function checkChildLocation() {
  if(document.getElementById('myIFrame').location != startingLocation) {
    /* the iframe has changed */
  }
}
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this violates the cross origin policy, and cannot be accomplished. Have a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy